# Adding user input to a list , then deleting it if the input exists in the list or appending it if it does not

Tags: python, python-3.x

So I want to ask a user to enter a letter for a pre-made list. If that letter already exists in that list , I want to have that letter deleted , if it does not exists in the list , I want it appended to the list.
This is the code I'm using right now :

```
list1= ['a','b','c','d','e']
letter=input("please input a letter ")
for letter in list1:
    if letter in list1:
         del list1[letter]
         print(list1)
    else:
         print(list1.append(letter)
```

It gives the type-error that list indices must be integers not string. How do I go about this ?

Comment: Try using `list1.remove(letter)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to pop the letter at the index. Also there is no need for the for loop. Edited answer to incorporate @lukasz comment.

```
list1= ['a','b','c','d','e']
letter=input("please input a letter ")
if letter in list1:
    list1.remove(letter)
else:
    print(list1.append(letter))
```

Comment: When don't you try searching in set(list1) instead?

Comment: Ah yeah , I just tried it with the .remove() method. It worked. Thanks a bunch to both you and  Łukasz R. :)

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple it is. Remove the value if it exists in the list, append if not.

```
list1= ['a','b','c','d','e']
letter=raw_input("please input a letter ")
list1.remove(letter) if letter in list1 else list1.append(letter)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the letter is in `list1`, you can use `remove` to delete it, and `append` can be used to add the new letter to the end of the list. The following script lets you see it working:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c','d','e']

while True:
    print('Current list:', list1)
    letter = input("Please input a letter: ")

    if letter in list1:
        list1.remove(letter)
    else:
        list1.append(letter)
```

For example:

```
Current list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
Please input a letter: f
Current list: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
Please input a letter: b
Current list: ['a', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
Please input a letter: a
Current list: ['c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
```